# Is there a difference between req.response.headers.add and req.response.headers.contentType

Tags: dart, server-side-rendering

I am trying to serve html css and javascript using Dart as server side language however I want to know is there a difference between these two statements.

```
req.response.headers.add("Content-Type",contentType),
req.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.html;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `contentType` getter/setter is a convenience feature which allows you to access `.headers["Content-Type"]`, aka. [`.headers[HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader]`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.4/dart-io/HttpHeaders/contentTypeHeader-constant.html), as a [`ContentType`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.4/dart-io/ContentType-class.html) instead of a `String`.

It converts the `ContentType` to string when storing, and parses it back out when reading (the code: [code](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/849459109a364f7f80ca82647ad088a4a6157ebc/sdk/lib/_http/http_headers.dart#L295)), but it is backed by the same string as `.headers`.